# Converting Web API to Servicestack - JObject to JsonObject

Tags: parsing, dynamic, servicestack, json

I am trying to convert my Web Api based project to Servicestack and now I am having a problem when converting a complex (client) side object graph to a C# dynamic class (because it is complex and mainly used client side I do not want to create a C# representation of this). Here is some stripped code (not the exact code so there could be mistakes):

OLD CODE:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Save([FromBody] JObject jsonData)
{

    dynamic jsonDataAsDynamic = jsonData;
    var test = (JObject)jsonDataAsDynamic.TheComplexObjectGraphStringified; 
}
```

The above code works without problems.

NEW CODE:

```
[Route("/SomeRoute/Save")]
public class PostRequest
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string TheComplexObjectGraphStringified { get; set; }
}

public object Post(PostRequest request)
{
    var test = JsonObject.Parse(request.TheComplexObjectGraphStringified);

}
```

NOTE: Because I am a newbie on Servicestack I do not (yet) know if JsonObject.Parse does the same as a cast to JObject.

My Javascript call is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: <save url>,
    data: '{' +
        '"A":' + a +
       ',"B":' + b +
       ',"TheComplexObjectGraphStringified":' + JSON.stringify(TheComplexObjectGraph) +
    '}',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
```

Example data:

After applying stringify with javascript the content (ON THE CLIENT) of 'TheComplexObjectGraphStringified' is (for your interest it is Google data):

{"zoom":12,"tilt":0,"overlays":[{"uniqueid":1387287972247, "paths":[[{"lat":52.096898776519055,"lng":5.655044395378695},{"lat":52.093607315804085,"lng":5.655044395378695}]]}],"center":{"lat":52.095253046161574,"lng":5.65941103165494}}

Now the strange thing is, when this arrives on the server in property 'TheComplexObjectGraphStringified' the quotes are removed! Debugger data:

"{zoom:12,tilt:0,overlays: <... rest of string...>"

As you can see zoom is not quoted any more (I am expecting something like "{\"zoom\": 12"

I noticed if I add some escaped quotes by hand using the debugger JsonObject.Parse seems to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems are occurring because you aren't serializing your data correctly before it arrives at the ServiceStack server.

- In your code you have stringified the complex data, but then manually tried building the JSON data surrounding the object, before sending it to the server.
- The problem with this approach is you haven't escaped the complex object.

To fix the issue you should stringify the data object:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: <save url>,
    data: JSON.stringify({
        A: a, 
        B: b, 
        TheComplexObjectGraphStringified: JSON.stringify(TheComplexObjectGraph)
    }),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    ...
```

I highly recommend you avoid writing the JSON string manually.

> I noticed if I add some escaped quotes by hand using the debugger JsonObject.Parse seems to work.

Yes there is no reason given valid code that `JsonObject.Parse` shouldn't work.

> I do not (yet) know if JsonObject.Parse does the same as a cast to JObject.

Yes it behaves similarly. You can see examples of [ServiceStack.Text's support for dynamic JSON here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#supports-dynamic-json). *The examples there include a Google Maps data example too. It may be useful.*

Hope this helps.

Comment: Many many thanks and I feel like a greenhorn considering my non-stringify solution. It works now! And the supplied link is really helpful.